# cannot connect 2 selected anchors in GIMP image editor

Tags: gimp

Is there any way to connect 2 selected anchors in GIMP to make a simple line?

[image]

When I'm starting new Paths tool drawing I can connect anchors when working with same drawing, but after restarting GIMP, opening saved drawing, selecting 2 anchors like in picture, it won't let me connect two anchors with line no matter how I press hotkeys and etc.

Comment: when I'm starting new Paths tool drawing I can connect anchors when working with same drawing, but after restarting GIMP, opening saved drawing, selecting 2 anchors like in picture, it won't let me connect two anchors with line no matter how I press hotkeys and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking to add a line between the two anchors, the answer is no, you can have at most two segments out of an anchor. You can have a second pair of anchors that overlaps the existing two and draw a line between them, but these would technically be distinct anchors.

See [this](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Paths-Basics) for some background information.

Comment: I just understood, that closed loop can be made and no other segment points can be connected. Thank you for clarifying me!